# what's the difference in memory allocation of a structure variable and a structure type pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

here s is the variable of  the structure stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 80

int main(void)
{
    struct stack
    {
        int size;
        int top;
        int *arr;
    }s;
    s.size=SIZE;
    s.top=-1;
    s.arr=malloc(s.size*sizeof(int));
    
    return 0;
}
```

and here *s is the pointer of the struct stack, but what is the pointer pointing at? what's the variable address since structure definition doesn't take any memory if its not made a variable ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 80

int main(void)
{
    struct stack
    {
        int size;
        int top;
        int *arr;
    }*s;
    s->size=SIZE;
    s->top=-1;
    s->arr=malloc(s->size*sizeof(int));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since you have not assigned any value to the pointer, it is pointing to some random location. This could be `NULL`, some valid address in your program's variables segment, or anything else, including invalid space. Expect any behavior, this is what "Undefined Behavior" means.

Comment: @thebusybee: When a pointer is not initialized, its value is *indeterminate*. This means it may behave as if it does not have any fixed value. That is different from pointing to a random location or to any location at all. Since it may be difficult to learn this concept, students should not be misled by incorrect information about “random” locations.

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of code you declare a variable `s` of type `struct stat`.

Then you assign its members with some values. This is fine and works because when you declare that variable, some memory is allocated for it.

In your second example you declare a variable `s` of type `struct stack *`. This is just a pointer to a `struct`, specifically one with type `struct stack`.

Now remember that `s` is a pointer, and since it is uninitialized, its value is  not exactly known, established or defined.

So when you try to assign the pointer `s` with values with the code

```
s->size=SIZE;
s->top=-1;
s->arr=malloc(s->size*sizeof(int));
```

What you are actually doing is assigning values to a uninitialized pointer. This will invoke undefined behaviour.

To fix this you must assign the pointer `s`:

```
s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

Note:

Always check if `malloc()` has failed in your code:

```
if (s == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed");
    // error procedure
}
```

Also always `free` anything you allocate with `malloc`:

```
free(s);
```

Comment: Pedantic nitpicking on "This will most likely either lead to a segmentation fault or undefined behaviour."  A segmentation fault is one possibility when undefined behavior is invoked. Perhaps "This will invoke undefined behaviour which may include a segmentation fault."

Comment: Also, be sure to `free` the memory allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: Keep in mind that UB _may_ include the program working exactly as expected.